# How to solve permission error on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, cloudbees

I was able to install Wordpress on Cloudbees using [this](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/wordpress-clickstart) plugin. Now if I try to try to install a theme or plugin by uploading it from Wordpress admin I receive:

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/07. Is its parent
>   directory writable by the server?

Is there any way I can connect to the cloudbees server where my app is hosted and change permission of wp-content to allow uploads? Or is there any other workaround for this issue?

I don't see any FTP/SSH ways in cloudbees tutorials to connect to the vms where apps are hosted in the cloud...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the runtime environment you don't have the possibility of doing ssh/ftp, but maybe there is a workaround which might work for you.

Themes could be installed from git. User should clone the repository created by the ClickStart, then add the theme in 'wp-content/themes', and finally do a commit + push, and everything will be built automatically and then deployed again to the runtime environment.

Comment: This solution works but its pretty ugly to deploy new stuff whenever we want to add a plugin or theme so for wordpress we're going to try another hosting unfortunately.